# Decode and check SAML 1.1 signature with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, saml

I use something like this to verify my SAML 1.1 http://www.cedricascoop.be/2011/08/how-to-check-x509-signature-of-saml-token/ and it's working.

But I can see that there are classes in the framework .NET that seems to talk about SAML https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens(v=vs.110).aspx
But I can't achieved to use something ...

My strating point is a XML like this :

```
<samlp:Response ResponseID="xxx" MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" IssueInstant="..." Recipient="xxx" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:protocol">
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        [...]
        <ds:SignatureValue>xxx</ds:SignatureValue>
    </ds:Signature>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="samlp:Success"/>
    </samlp:Status>
    <saml:Assertion MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" AssertionID="xxx" IssueInstant="..." Issuer="xxx" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion">
        <saml:Conditions NotBefore="..." NotOnOrAfter="..."/>
        <saml:AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationInstant="..." AuthenticationMethod="...">
            <saml:Subject>
                <saml:NameIdentifier Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">xxx</saml:NameIdentifier>
                <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                    <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:...</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
                </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
            </saml:Subject>
        </saml:AuthenticationStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Any tips ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to achieve and why is that failing?

Comment: I want to use built-in core object that seems to be here for that